# Dell monitor stuck in power save mode

Tags: mac, macbook, external-display, displayport

I recently bought a Dell P2414H monitor for my office work. Since I am using a MacBook Air, I also bought a Belkin docking station to connect all my peripherals. While all of them appear to work normally, the monitor is stuck in power save mode.

I tried to connect it both with DisplayPort and VGA, but nothing seems to change.
Then, I borrowed from a friend of mine an Apple Thunderbolt to VGA adapter and plugged it directly to the laptop. In this case, the monitor works.

Do you have any suggestion to make it work without having to buy a new adapter and especially to plug a new cable to the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the docking station needs "drivers" even on a mac. I installed them from the  [belkin website](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/sla.php?fileid=169) and now the screen works properly.